# What is the metric on a cone?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

I'm trying to learn differential geometry.  I thought a cone would be an easy place to start with calculating a metric, shape operator, what have you.

First of all, by the way, when I say "cone" I mean the map $f: (x,y) \rightarrow (x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$  Nothing fancy.

So I run through a prescription for getting a metric: $g_{ij} = \partial_i f_k \partial_j f_k$ where repeated indices indicate sum.

I get $G=((2x^2+y^2)\,dx^2+2xy\,dx\,dy+(x^2+2y^2)\,dy^2)/(x^2+y^2)$

Can someone just tell me whether this is right or not, and show me how to correct myself if I have gone wrong?  I can't find this formula or, surprising to me, any other formula anywhere.  I thought this would be a widely discussed example.  Maybe I ought to just stop being cheap and buy a book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks pretty much right. You'll know more whether you're doing things right once you compute the second fundamental form as well, because then you can compute the Gaussian curvature, and the Gaussian curvature for a cone is everywhere zero. (Why? Because if you slit it along a line, you can unroll it onto a piece of the flat plane).

That's a reason that the cone is NOT a great example. A "Monge patch" (the graph of $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y, f(x, y))$ for some $f$) is generally a good deal more informative, because you can get nonzero answers. If you pick $f$ quadratic in $x$ and $y$, everything comes out *really* nicely.

Comment: Much obliged!  Thanks.  Actually, the zero curvature is one of the reasons I picked the cone.  I figure if I can go through all the machinations and get to zero, which I knew to be the case ahead of time, then I figure I am doing things right.  It all seems to be working out, BTW.  Thanks again.

Comment: That makes sense. You might want to also try re-doing your work in polar coordinates on the cone, i.e., $r =$ distance from apex, $\theta = $ angle around axis, starting from some plane. If $\phi$ is the (constant) cone angle, this gives $z = r \cos \phi, x = r \sin \phi \cos \theta, y = r \sin \phi \sin \theta$. The first few derivative are uglier, but most of the computations end up nicer, making the case for "natural" coordinates.